# How to do this Query on MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a query to show me the entrance(Where TerminalID = 1) and exit (Where TerminalID = 2) per day, but if UserID just have a exit mark for this day, use 08:00:00 on entrance value and if do not have a exit mark, set exit value with 20:00:00 with the same day, i need to know how many days the IDUser was here and how many time per day, that's my table:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe1dd/1)

```
ID  TransactionTime TerminalID UserID
1   2014-04-01 08:59    1      1
2   2014-04-01 09:09    1      1
3   2014-04-01 09:59    2      1
4   2014-04-01 10:59    1      1
5   2014-04-01 18:59    2      1
6   2014-05-01 08:59    1      1
7   2014-04-01 09:59    1      2
8   2014-04-01 18:59    2      2
9   2014-05-01 08:59    2      2
```

**The result that I need is:**

```
UserID  MarkEntrance    MarkExit          TimeHere
1     2014-04-01 08:59  2014-04-01 09:59  01:00:00
1     2014-04-01 10:59  2014-04-01 18:59  08:00:00
1     2014-05-01 08:59  2014-05-01 20:00  11:01:00
```

**And I can do this:**

```
SELECT TOP 1000
      pna.UserID
      ,Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) as DateOfMark
      ,MarkEntrance = 
CASE WHEN 
(SELECT MIN(TransactionTime) FROM [NGAC_AUTHLOG] as na WHERE na.TerminalID = 1 AND Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime, 103) = Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) AND na.UserID = pna.UserID ) IS NOT NULL
THEN 
(SELECT MIN(TransactionTime) FROM [NGAC_AUTHLOG] as na WHERE na.TerminalID = 1 AND Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime, 103) = Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) AND na.UserID = pna.UserID )
ELSE  convert(datetime,Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) + ' 08:00:00')
END
      ,MarkExit = 
CASE WHEN 
(SELECT MAX(TransactionTime) FROM [NGAC_AUTHLOG] as na WHERE na.TerminalID = 2 AND Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime, 103) = Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) AND na.UserID = pna.UserID ) IS NOT NULL
THEN 
(SELECT MAX(TransactionTime) FROM [NGAC_AUTHLOG] as na WHERE na.TerminalID = 2 AND Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime, 103) = Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) AND na.UserID = pna.UserID )
ELSE convert(datetime,Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) + ' 20:00:00')
END
      ,TimeHere = 
Convert(char(8),
CASE WHEN 
(SELECT MAX(TransactionTime) FROM [NGAC_AUTHLOG] as na WHERE na.TerminalID = 2 AND Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime, 103) = Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) AND na.UserID = pna.UserID ) IS NOT NULL
THEN 
(SELECT MAX(TransactionTime) FROM [NGAC_AUTHLOG] as na WHERE na.TerminalID = 2 AND Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime, 103) = Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) AND na.UserID = pna.UserID )
ELSE convert(datetime,Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) + ' 20:00:00')
END - 
CASE WHEN 
(SELECT MIN(TransactionTime) FROM [NGAC_AUTHLOG] as na WHERE na.TerminalID = 1 AND Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime, 103) = Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) AND na.UserID = pna.UserID ) IS NOT NULL
THEN 
(SELECT MIN(TransactionTime) FROM [NGAC_AUTHLOG] as na WHERE na.TerminalID = 1 AND Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime, 103) = Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) AND na.UserID = pna.UserID )
ELSE  convert(datetime,Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103) + ' 08:00:00')
END
, 14)
  FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG as pna
  GROUP BY pna.UserID, Convert(char(10),pna.TransactionTime, 103)
```

But in my query i just know the first entrance and the last exit by UserID, but he can have many marks per day.

**(I used MIN and MAX but this way just show one big mark, merging all the marks of the day)**

Comment: Can you please add a table with the expected result to the query? I'm a bit lost in what you want to achieve. But the question is interesting, otherway ;)

Comment: Yeah, of course! I edited with the result that I need :)

Comment: This appears to be a prime candidate for a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. First union part matches all the records for Entrance to exit and orphan entrances. Second part of the union takes care of the orphaned exit records.

**Solution 1:**

```
SELECT *, Convert(char(8), MarkExit - MarkEntrance, 14) TimeHere
FROM
(
SELECT
    A.UserID, A.TransactionTime MarkEntrance, ISNULL(ExitTime, DateAdd(hh, 20, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.TransactionTime, 101))) MarkExit 
FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG A
OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT MIN(TransactionTime) ExitTime
  FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG B
  WHERE B.TerminalID = 2
  AND B.UserID = A.UserID
  AND B.TransactionTime > A.TransactionTime
) B
WHERE A.TerminalID = 1

UNION ALL

--This looks for orphan Exit Record
SELECT A.UserID, DateAdd(hh, 8, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), max(A.TransactionTime), 101)), max(A.TransactionTime)
FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG A
WHERE A.TerminalID = 2 
AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 
    FROM
       (SELECT UserID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TransactionTime, 101) T2Date, COUNT(*) T2Count
       FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG
       WHERE TerminalID = 2
       GROUP BY UserID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TransactionTime, 101)) X
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT UserID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TransactionTime, 101) T1Date, COUNT(*) T1Count
       FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG
       WHERE TerminalID = 1
       GROUP BY UserID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TransactionTime, 101)) Y
          ON X.UserID = Y.UserID
          AND X.T2Date = Y.T1Date
    WHERE X.T2Count > ISNULL(Y.T1Count,0)
    AND X.UserID = A.UserID
    AND X.T2Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TransactionTime, 101)
    )
GROUP BY A.UserID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TransactionTime, 101)
) X
```

**Solution 2:** 
Assuming if there is an orphan exit record there is only 1 exit record for that day for that user

```
SELECT *, Convert(char(8), MarkExit - MarkEntrance, 14) TimeHere
FROM
(
SELECT
    A.UserID, A.TransactionTime MarkEntrance, ISNULL(ExitTime, DateAdd(hh, 20, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.TransactionTime, 101))) MarkExit 
FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG A
OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT MIN(TransactionTime) ExitTime
  FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG B
  WHERE B.TerminalID = 2
  AND B.UserID = A.UserID
  AND B.TransactionTime > A.TransactionTime
) B
WHERE A.TerminalID = 1

UNION ALL
--This looks for orphan Exit Record
SELECT A.UserID, DateAdd(hh, 8, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.TransactionTime, 101)), A.TransactionTime
FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG A
WHERE A.TerminalID = 2 
AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 
    FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG B
    WHERE B.TerminalID = 1
     AND A.UserID = B.UserID
      AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.TransactionTime, 101) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), B.TransactionTime, 101))  
) X
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed4b3/1)

Comment: I'm checking your query, but I think that you made this right!! I'll mark your answer soon.

Comment: I have one problem :( if the user have two marks Type 1(Entrance) before mark exit, I need to use just the first mark to check the `TimeHere` (just disregard the second entrance mark in this case), this query return the `TimeHere` for two Entrances,  SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9e0c/3 , but this is the last update that I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are many variations of the above problem that needs to be figured out. Two entrance and two exits but the second entrance is before the first exit.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0aa5/1

Comment: How about 1 entrance and 2 exits. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7513/1 . This may look striaght forward but if we combine with bigger set of data, complexity will increase further.

Comment: If we have 2 exits, use the last one for the same day, but in your first sqlfiddle(2 entrances and 2 exits) I need to use the first entrance and the last exit. Did I explain correctly for you? This query is confusing my head haha

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Note I haven't run the query, so there might be a simple syntax error in it(mainly in conversions - really not sure about that), if there is an issue, please let me know in a comment.

```
;WITH minEntranceInDay as(
    SELECT MIN(transactionTime) EntranceTime,Convert(DateTime( Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime)), 103) Day, UserId    
    FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG WHERE TerminalId = 1
    GROUP BY Convert(DateTime( Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime)), 103), UserId
), maxExitInDay as(
    SELECT MAX(transactionTime) ExitTime, Convert(DateTime( Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime)) Day, UserId    
    FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG WHERE TerminalId = 2
    GROUP BY Convert(DateTime( Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime)), 103), UserId
), usersAndDates as(
    SELECT DISTINCT Convert(DateTime( Convert(char(10),na.TransactionTime))  Day, UserId    
    FROM NGAC_AUTHLOG 
), GroupedData As (
    SELECT ud.UserId, COALESCE(me.minEntranceInDay,Dateadd(h,8,ud.Day)) EntranceTime, COALESCE(mx.maxExitInDay,Dateadd(h,20,ud.Day)) ExitDate
    FROM usersAndDates ud 
    LEFT JOIN minEntranceInDay me ON me.UserId = ud.UserId AND me.Day = ud.Day 
    LEFT JOIN maxExitInDay mx ON mx.UserId = ud.UserId AND mx.Day = ud.Day
)
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(h,EntranceTime,ExitTime)+":"+DATEDIFF(m,EntranceTime,ExitTime)+":"+DATEDIFF(s,EntranceTime,ExitTime) TimeHere
FROM GroupedData
```

Comment: Tomas, We have a problem haha, the UserID can have more than 1 mark per day and i need to know the time here in each mark. (I used MIN and MAX but this way just show one big mark, merging all the marks of the day)

Comment: @AlessandroGomes Can you please show that in the example in the first post, as it would look for user 1 on 1/4?

Comment: I inserted the real result and I updated the values on table to describe the case that I commented.

Comment: @AlessandroGomes Are you aware that entries 1 and 5 are the same? If this is correct, it will make it a lot more difficult? Here is what I have so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95fc0/4/0

Comment: I'm sorry! the ID 5 is 1/5/2014

Comment: And in ID 5, I need to set exit value with 20:00:00 because I don't have a exit mark for this day.

Comment: @AlessandroGomes Sorry, I give up... That's too difficult for me! This is what I have so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a43f/5/0

Comment: No problem, that's really hard to me too. Thanks for trying.